# flutter: HttpException: Failed Forbidden from the twitter plugin

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, twitter, twitter-login

I'm trying to implement twitter login in my app but it doesn't work, returning an errorMessage in the AppResult object. Does anyone know a solution?

The packages I use are
twitter_login: ^4.2.3

firebase:
firebase_core: ^1.11.0
firebase_auth: ^3.3.5

Twitter config (User authentication settings page):

- OAuth 1.0a enabled (is it the proper one for the plugin?)
- Request email from users: disabled
- App permissions: Read
- Callback URI: https://project-name.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
- webiste url: https://www.google.com/
- besides that everything is empty

Firebase config:

- twitter auth enabled
- api key set (checked it like 10 times)
- api secret set (same thing)

Android manifest:

inside the activity tag:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
            <!-- Registered Callback URLs in TwitterApp -->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="app-name.firebaseapp.com" />
            <!-- host is option -->
        </intent-filter>
```

after the activity tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
```

The code itself:

```
 final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
      apiKey: '123 it's the same one',
      apiSecretKey: 'proper one',
      redirectURI: 'https://app-name.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler');

  final authResult = await twitterLogin.login();
  print(authResult.errorMessage); // prints out HttpException: Failed Forbidden
```

The code opens the link with the authentication, but after clicking on "authorize app", it returns to the app with the errorMessage "HttpException: Failed Forbidden"
Also, the authToken and the authTokenSecret are both null.

If you need any additional information, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a little bit of digging I found the answer to my question. In order to make it work I did the following:

1. changed the android scheme to appname://
2. removed the android host

   ```
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
    <!-- Registered Callback URLs in TwitterApp -->
    <data android:scheme="appname" />
        <!-- host is option -->
    </intent-filter>
   ```
3. changed the redirect url inside the twitter config to appname://
4. got elevated access for the twitter portal
5. used the loginV2 function along with OAuth2 instead of OAuth1

   ```
    Future<UserCredential> _signInWithTwitter() async {
      // Create a TwitterLogin instance


     final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
          apiKey: '123',
          apiSecretKey: '1234',
          redirectURI: 'appname://');

      // Trigger the sign-in flow
      final authResult = await twitterLogin.loginV2();
      print(authResult.toMap());

      // Create a credential from the access token
      final twitterAuthCredential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: authResult.authToken!,
        secret: authResult.authTokenSecret!,
      );

      // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
      return await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredential);
    }
   ```
6. Didn't use the callback provided by firebase at all (this is mentioned in the README too, but I'm too stupid to check)

Answer (score 1):

Your getting Forbidden http exception. So, in the official documentation it says -

> The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. An accompanying error message will explain why.

And the solution is given as -

> Check that your developer account includes access to the endpoint you’re trying to use. You may also need to get your App allowlisted (e.g. Engagement API or Ads API) or sign up for access.

You can check - [Twitter API Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting)

Hope it helps.